# Apache Rewrite CLEAN url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I'm wondering if anyone would be willing to help me, or tell me if it's possible to do what I'm thinking of for my urls.

So I want the urls to be like so

http://www.example.com/(seriesname)/season/(seasonnumber)/episode/(episodenumber)

The variables surrounded by '()' will need to be php variables that I can parse. Is this possible/any help on the regex for mod rewrite.

And I could also go to lets say sub parts of the url to just show all episodes in a season or all seasons. EG:
http://www.example.com/(seriesname)/season/(seasonnumber) will display all episodes in specified season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/season/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1&season=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/season/([^/]*)/episode/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1&season=$2&episode=$3
```

Comment: One problem I'm having though is 
RewriteRule ^/series/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1

Isn't rewriting when I go to http://localhost/series/xxx