# Dynamic pages and URLs

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I'm working on a small system which allows to navigate through pages easily. Where I'm having trouble is the URL structure -- I would like to avoid having unnecessary parameters in my URL for no SEO value.

So far, I've been working with page structures like so :

```
http://www.example.com/pages.php?id=3
```

However, I would like to dynamically create a structure where my link is more SEO friendly, but where I can still query my database for the appropriate page.

As of right now, this is my (much simplified) pages structure :

```
id | url            | title
-------------------------------------
1  | my-first-page  | My first page
2  | my-second-page | My second page
3  | my-third-page  | My third page
```

And so on.

Is there a way to have query the "my-first-page" from "http://example.com/my-first-page" ?

I know the $_GET function allows me to get the page id (in the case 3) from a link similar to "http://www.example.com/pages.php?id=3", but this is as far as my current knowledge extends.

Can someone point me into the appropriate direction ?

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Rewrite CLEAN url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176618/apache-rewrite-clean-url)

Comment: Look up mod_rewrite or IIS rewriting modules depending on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on **htAccess** structure (the Apache's tutorial is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html)).

Actually, you will still work with the `$_GET` but, with the usage of `RewriteRule`, you can extend this and make more user-friendly as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. Wasn't looking at the right place, no wonder I couldn't get it to work !

Answer (score 0):

something like this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ pages.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then if your link was pages.php/1 it would equate to pages.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the way WordPress does it, is that it redirect all traffic towards a single URL (a router) using .htaccess, which then looks at `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and loads the right page that the user requested.